# many to many validation in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, postman

I have three models first is Activity and second is User and they linked to each other with many to many relationship as following and the last one is rating which has a foreign key from activity as following:

models.py

```
class Activity(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(blank=True, unique=True, max_length=100)
    rating_average = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=0, max_length=1)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='activitymembers')



class ActivityRating(models.Model):
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, related_name='activity', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    rate = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rate_user', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializer.py

```
class ActivityRateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        created_by = kwargs['context']['request'].user
        super(ActivityRateSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['created_by'].queryset = User.objects.filter(id=created_by.id)

    class Meta:
        model = ActivityRating
        fields = ['id', 'activity', 'rate', 'created_by']
    def create(self, validated_data):

        obj = ActivityRating.objects.create(**validated_data)
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

its work fine but what i need is: how to add validator that make the rating is impossible unless you are member in activity

please any one has a solution help me ,

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by overriding the [**`validate()`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) method of serializer as,

```
class ActivityRateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super(ActivityRateSerializer, self).validate(attrs)  # calling default validation
        if not Activity.objects.filter(members=self.context['request'].user).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("your validation error")
        return attrs

    class Meta:
        model = ActivityRating
        fields = ['id', 'activity', 'rate', 'created_by']
```

---

I've modified your most of the code, because DRF providing the feature to fetch the ***`requested user`*** from context by using [**`CurrentUserDefault()`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault) along with [**`PrimaryKeyRelatedField()`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)

Also, your **`create()`** method is irrelevent here since it's not doing anything different from the orginal logic

Comment: is there any need to call `attrs = super(ActivityRateSerializer, self).validate(attrs)` ? Is that not the default behavior?

Comment: By calling `super()` method, it will run the ***default validation*** over the received data